# Как эффективней писать ПО

Tags: java, методология

Пишу средний проект на java. 
Сроки довольно сжатые.
Как лучше распределить свое время:
1.Писать код по намеченной логике, и уже в конце начать его тестировать.
2.Или разбить логику на под задачи и писать/тестировать по кусочкам.

Второй способ кажется логичней, но допустим написав 1-5 пункты своей задачи и протестировав я пойму что 8 и 9 пункты вынуждают меня 1-5 пункты переписать. Так собственно и произошло, поэтому я этот вопрос и задаю. В итоге время на тесты было потрачено впустую.

И если есть хорошие статьи на эту тему буду благодарен.

Comment: `протестировав я пойму что 8 и 9 пункты вынуждают меня 1-5 пункты переписать.` - это норма.

Comment: возможно есть приемы позволяющие минимизировать эти потери. я уже понял что грамоздкое планирование и щепетильно выверенно ТЗ мне жизнь не облегчили.

Comment: Думаю что для минимизации потерь нужно разрабатывать командой, где каждый занимается своей частью. Но если один, то начинать с самого начала, к примеру, авторизации, регистрации. И дальше идти постепенно. Протетстить можно, но не тратить много время. Выделите самые главные участки и делайте их. более мелкие детали можно либо в процессе какой-то крупной части или уже после неё.

Comment: @Padawan, сначала выделяете крупные блоки (подзадачи, модули), причем максимально изолированные друг от друга, продумываете как они между собой будут общаться (интерфейсы, протоколы), дальше уже прорабатываете эти блоки отдельно. При изменениях в одном блоке стараетесь не менять интерфейс, тогда не потребуются изменения в других блоках. При изменении интерфейса согласованно изменяете блоки, которые этот интерфейс связывает.

Comment: ну да использовать ООП для защиты от себя же самого это хороший совет.)

Comment: самое главное - инкапсуляция

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agile (итеративное) управление проектом удлиняет сроки разработки (во втором варианте вы по сути описываете именно agile технологию), но минимизирует риски не неверного проектирования.

К сожалению в 90% проектов при написании ТЗ (или планировании проекта) невозможно на 100% сразу определить все возможные проблемы. Как правильно отметили вы же сами ответили, проект после какой-то стадии начинает жить своей собственной жизнью, а именно:

> 1-5 пункты своей задачи и протестировав я пойму что 8 и 9 пункты вынуждают меня 1-5 пункты переписать.

Если проект небольшой или вы уверены в том, что риски неверного проектирования минимальны, то можно сразу писать и тестировать в конце.

Можно выбрать другой способ разбить задачу не на 8-9 пунктов, а только на 2-3 пункта ибо чем больше пунктом/итераций, тем более вы даете свободу нелинейности проектирования, зато чем меньше пунктов, тем больше рисков неверного проектирования.

Соответственно, вам нужно определить этапы/итерации проекта не исходя из внутренней логики проекта, а исходя из рисков неверного проектирования, то есть если вы видите в проекте, скажем 10 логических этапов, из которых 5 вам хорошо понятны, а еще 5 "темный лес", то имеет смысл проект разделить на 6 этапов: на 1 этап в котором собрать 5 понятных вам пунктов, а 5 непонятных так и оставить как 5 этапов. Понятно, что такое не всегда возможно, но тем не менее - как общая идея.

Comment: "а исходя из рисков неверного проектирования" - да отличный совет, думаю что этим и буду руководствоваться. спасибо.